# Information on L-Systems

Tags: c++, algorithm, procedural-programming, procedural-generation, l-systems

I am about to start a project for university to build a procedural city for a pre existing project.

I was wondering if any of you have had any experience coding L-Systems before and know a good place for me to start out. I have done a bit of work before using procedural methods and Perlin Noise and fBm so I get the premise of what an L-System is in the fractal sense. I am more looking for a place where maybe can push me in the direction of coding the L-System.
Any help or technical documents you can point me towards would be great.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did a project on using L-Systems to procedurally generate 3D trees and found the book "[The Algorithmic Beauty of Plants](http://algorithmicbotany.org/papers/#abop)" helpful. It's available for free at that link. Not directly related to procedural cities, but very interesting, and a good resource to learn about L-Systems, I think.

Comment: Yeah i was going to start  out with something like a plant, or tree, then work my way up to road structures, i will have a look at this book.

Comment: Roads? Are they usually fractal? I'd expect roads to be more ... man-made, less random and noisy, with more of a sense of purpose or direction to them. But maybe I'm just being naïve. :)

Comment: ... Or American ;) European roads have a bit more of history, no square grids here.

Comment: Yeah L-SYstems have been used many times to create roads in procedural cities, generally if you go to ACM and look up procedural city some examples come up. Also i believe the makers of darwinia used L-Systems to create the road system in the procedural city builder they are developing.

Comment: @xyz .Which application did you use for the 3d representation of L-system because i also want to represent some trees in 3d. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I'm working on an L-system project too, and it's been tremendously helpful to look at some pre-existing code: [lsystem.py](http://www.berniepope.id.au/html/pycol/lsystem.py.html) - There's also pseudocode in [Fundamentals of Natural Computing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1584886439) which I found really helpful. It takes you through the process of using turtle graphics to create a simple L-system tree, and quickly moves on to more advanced stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Well ... I'll go first and hand you the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-system) link, which looks reasonably meaty, and has quite a few external links of its own.