# plant growth simulation algorithm

Tags: c++

where i can get the plant growth simulation algorithm for C or C++ language....???

Comment: When you say "plant growth simulation" do you mean something like there's an individual plant and you want to model its growth or something where there's an area and you want to model the growth of different plants across that area?

Comment: As an aside, this topic would be more appropriate for the future bioinformatics site (still in Area 51, http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6729/bioinformatics).

Comment: you're question doesn't make sense, this is why : the principle of an algorithm is that it's just a recipe, it's not code, so it has nothing to do with any language, next : this place is not a fast food, you don't just order what you need and then it doesn't just get delivered to you : if you have a specific problem, people will help you to resolve it, this is not google search (which by the way would easily give you many scientific papers on how to implement what you are wanting to obtain)

Answer (score 1):

The lpfg language is based on C++.  The resources at http://algorithmicbotany.org/ will help you get started.  You can also request a demo version of the software.

Answer (score 1):

It would have helped if you mentioned more in your question, though you're probably referring to [this](http://www.cs.earlham.edu/~loretfl/plantmodeling/Plant_Modeling.pdf) or [fractals](http://www.panda3d.org/manual/index.php/Sample_Programs:_Fractal_Plants) or maybe [L-systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914596/information-on-l-systems).